# Does accomplishments progress carry across multiple playthroughs?

Tags: mass-effect-3, achievements

Mass Effect 3 has several "*Do X Y times*" accomplishments for example, the 
"**Bruiser**" accomplishment which requires a certain number of melee kills.

Do these accomplishments require me to complete all of these action on one playthorugh or does it stack between multiple saves? If progress does carry over between playthoughs, do I need to import a save into a new game for progress to carry over or can I start an entirely new save?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

All Mass Effect 3 Achievements carry across playthroughs *and* profiles *and* multiplayer.

(And apparently Warp counts as setting enemies on fire? Who knew?)

Answer (score 1):

Achievements do carry across play throughs and saves.

Achievements also carry across deaths and reloads.  I had to reload the mission where you storm the camp and I killed a  brute while it was charging at me to get that achievement.  The game glitched, I reloaded, but I retained the achievement.

Comment: I've never heard of a game removing an achievement from you, but are you sure _progress_ towards achievements is kept over death? For example killing 5000 enemies. It's more common, in my experience, that gains to the count of achievements like that are removed between unsaved sections.

Comment: @staticbeast I can say specifically that the game did not remove my achievement, I can't say whether it would retain the progress.  I can say that the progress within a game where I died and used RESUME did carry over.